# Python: I am trying to call a function but the expected results won't come

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program prompts the user for numbers and when the user inputs 'done', it should give the largest value which was input and the smallest.

The function seems to work just fine for the largest variable. Which successfully takes the value of the first input. Later, the program keeps running, and it updates its value for the biggest value typed until done is pressed, so it will print it.

The Problem that I'm having is with the variable 'smallest'. Once the program runs, we type some numbers. When we insert ' done ', when the function is running, the Minimum (which relates to the variable *smallest*) will still have the value 'None'. So I'm having problems, through the function, to assign the smallest with the inputted values, so that it loses its None value.

If I run the function 'manually', i.e., I don't use this logic in a function, it'll work just fine and provide the results as expected.

```
inum = None
largest = None
smallest = None


def primeval(sizest) :
    if sizest is None :
        sizest = inum



while True:
    num = input ('Enter an integer number: ')
    if num == 'done' :
        break
    try:
        inum = int(num)
    except:
        print ('Invalid input')
        continue


    primeval (largest)

    primeval (smallest)



#if largest is None :                   #if done manually it'll work
 #   largest = inum
#if smallest is None :
 #   smallest = inum

  #resume of the code, after the 'manual primeval'  

if inum > largest :
    largest = inum
if  inum < smallest :
    smallest = inum

print ('Maximum is', largest)
print ('Minimum is', smallest)
```

Comment: What does `sizest` do?

Comment: Geeocode, hello. ' sizest ' is the parameter. It's a generic variable that will later be substituted by the argument, in this case (largest and smalles). Or so is what I understood of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach your problem differently:

```
numbers = []

while True:    
    user_input = input ('Enter an integer number (e for end!): ')

    if user_input == 'e':
        break
    try:
        number = int(user_input)
    except:
        print('Invalid input!')
        continue
    numbers.append(number)

if len(numbers):
    print('Maximum is', max(numbers))
    print('Minimum is', min(numbers))
```

You define a function that has no return value (return statement). In the function you want to work with the value inum, which you do not pass as parameter and which you do not define in the function. You shouldn't do that.

If you prefer a solution without a list:

```
smallest = None
largest = None

while True:    
    user_input = input ('Enter an integer number (e for end!): ')

    if user_input == 'e':
        break
    try:
        number = int(user_input)
    except:
        print('Invalid input!')
        continue

    if smallest is None or largest is None:
        smallest = number
        largest = number
    else:
        if number < smallest:
            smallest = number
        if number > largest:
            largest = number

print('Maximum is', largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

In this case it makes sense to initialize the two values ​​for the first time with None.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return a value:

```
def primeval(sizest,inum) :
    if sizest is None:
        sizest = inum
    return sizest
```

and use it like this:

```
largest = primeval(largest,inum)
```